# How do you make an expanded row in Material Design Lite Data Table

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I would like to create a `mdl-data-table` such that when I click on it.

My guess is just to add a row with `colspan` == number of columns when I choose to expand the row.  I was wondering if there was a better version than that.  Something that makes it look like that it is expanded with some existing styles rather than creating a new style.

In addition, if it can be "animated" as a slide down that pushes the other elements that would be a bonus.

Note the answer does not have to handle the clicking part, but just the "expanded" part

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution?